# How is interest calculated on P2P lending?

Tags: calculation, peer-to-peer-lending

I invested **102€** on a P2P site on a business loan. Here are the details of the loan:

- **Issue date:** 18.01.2020 (DD//MM/YYYY date format)
- **Maturity date:** 18.03.2020
- **Interest rate:** 13% annually.

I bought in on 29.01.2020. The total interest I got from the loan was 1.78€.

How I thought it was calculated:

[image: hi]

In my case: 102x13/(100*4) = **3.315€**

What is the actual formula for calculating P2P lending interest?

Comment: It depends on the term of the loan. How often does it compound? Are payments made periodically or only at the end of the loan?

Comment: @DStanley hi, payments are made periodically. I got 0.73€ on 18.02, and 1.05€ on 19.03. I got the principal back on 19.03.

Comment: I am confused. You mention 18.01.2020 to 18.03.2020 or two months. Then you include 4 months in your formula, but in your example calculate you use 3 months.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep sorry I had to add the division sign to the formula.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I just simplified the franction. 3/12 = 1/4. Should I change it to 3/12?

Comment: I was confused by the other mistake the missing slash. But you still have a two months vs three months problem.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep yes I felt quite embarrassed to notice that 18.01 to 18.02 is two months, not three :D. I am used to starting from 0 haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the dates in your example.

13% of 102 is 13.26 or 1.105 per month. So if you had been invested for the whole two months that would be 2.21 in interest

Turning the monthly rate into a daily rate and then looking at the 48 days between January 29th and March 18th means that you would be due 1.78.

Comment: Aha so they don't pay me for the whole term period. They only pay me the interest from when I start the investment. Thanks!